# Codeigniter - Adding Code to Constructor without affected to Specific Controller Function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**Short Version of this question**

How to write something like this (`if(Controller Function is Not "Login()" Function)`) in Codeigniter Constructor?

```
if(Controller Function is Not "Login()" Function)
{
    if(empty($this->session->userdata('user_id'))){
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

**Long Version of this question if is not clear the short version**

This is Admin controller of my codeigniter project

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        /**
        * 
        * 
        *  Here - I am going to check session is set or not.....
        * 
        * 
        */

    }

    public function login(){

    }

    public function update(){

    }

    public function edit(){

    }

    public function insert(){

    }

        /**
        * 
        * 
        *  And Many More Functions
        * 
        * 
        */

}
```

I am going to add following code part to **constructor**.

```
if(empty($this->session->userdata('user_id'))){
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

When I write this even I can't go to the `login()` function without session. How to write above code in **constructor** which not affect to the login function.

I am looking something like this,

```
if(Controller Function is Not "Login()" Function)
{
    if(empty($this->session->userdata('user_id'))){
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
function __construct()
{
    if(!($this->session->has_userdata('user_id')) && $this->router->fetch_method()!='login'){
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Set default controller is login

```
function __construct()
{
    if(!($this->session->has_userdata('user_id')) && $this->router->fetch_method() != "login"){
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

2.If not set default controller as login

```
function __construct()
{
    if(!($this->session->has_userdata('user_id'))&& $this->router->fetch_method() != "login"){
        redirect(base_url()."login");
    }
}
```